# Meteor Settings in a Deployed App

Tags: heroku, meteor, command-line-interface

This is probably a very basic question, but this is my first time using Meteor + Heroku and I can't seem to figure out how to use the settings.json file after deploying a Meteor app (currently using heroku).

From my hours of research on web, it seems that in order to use the settings in a deployed app, I have to do...

```
export METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"
```

At first I thought that this is meant to go to a boostrap file... Then I realized I was wrong when I started get reserved word errors (because of "export")

So... Where and how do I use this line? Am I suppose to use terminal to type this in? If so, how can I do that in Heroku?

Answer (score 23):

Basically: `heroku config:add METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat settings.json)"`.

Comment: And how do I do it if my deployment happens over heroku's Dropbox sync?

Answer (score 0):

The `heroku config:add...` command didn't work for me, but I was able to use heroku's dashboard to set my environment variables.  You can find the dashboard tab at: 
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/yourAppName/settings, and then click on `Reveal Config Vars`

Comment: And what exactly did you add? METEOR_SETTINGS and "$(cat settings.json)" respectively?

Comment: Once you click on `Reveal Config Vars` you can enter key / value pairs manually. (I didn't have that many pairs so it was easier than figuring out how to import the file.)

Comment: Do you know if it is equally safe when keeping a private key in the settings file as it is in the config vars?