# deploying meteor to heroku with --settings

Tags: meteor, heroku

I am deploying a meteor app to heroku. I have a settings.json file that needs to load with the app. Locally I'm able to run the app with meteor --settings settings.json.

How can I deploy it to Heroku so that it will load the settings.json file when the app launches?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998908/running-meteor-build-under-node-with-settings-argument/39000497#39000497

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339317/meteor-settings-in-a-deployed-app